# Slow requests when web scraping on a linux Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, web-crawler

I have to make a bunch of requests to scrape a website.
My computer alone would take too much time to make all theses requests, so I run my Python script on 7 virtual machines instead.
On my Windows PC, each request takes about 0.25sec, but on the virtual machines (linux), they usually take 0.15sec but about 1 request out of 4 seems to get stuck and takes 3-5sec. This considerably slows down the scraping...
Why is that ?! How can I make it work as good as on my small pc ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Using VMs seems to be a complete overkill... (and could be the source of your problme...) Why don't you use processes running in parallel?

Comment: I do use multiple processes, there are several processes running in parallel on each VM.

Comment: I still don't see the purpose of the VMs here (if they all run on the same host... but if hey don't you should explain your setup more in detall).

Comment: I needed to have multiple IPs to avoid the "429 Too many requests" error. The website seems to allow a maximum number of requests per minute per IP. So if I have more IPs I can make more requests per unit of time

Comment: If the VMs are in the same host, they all appear to have the same IP at the other end...

Comment: No, here they are really like distinct servers and each has at least 4 cores

Comment: you'll have to try to track down the latency (whether its really in requests, or in response timing). you are clearly hitting the limits of what the remote site allows by policy, so it makes sense that they would employ rate-limiting at multiple layers of their stack.

Comment: But there isn't this problem when I'm doing it on my pc, so I don't think this has something to do with the website's rate-limiting policies